# is it possible to access asp.net web application administration from the web not locally

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I think the question says it all,

Visual studio under ASP.net locally Development server gives the ability to access asp.net web application administration . but, if i want to access it on the web after publishing, is there any way to achieve that?

I am asking because I hope not to reinvent the wheel again!. I want to use the administration features, managing roles, users security for folders..etc.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase this question. What do you want to do when you get access?

Comment: I want to use the administration features, managing roles, users security for folders..etc.

Comment: So you dont want to remotely login to the server? Why do you want to do this through the web?

Comment: is there any open source similar replacement for the ASP.net application administration features?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done the way you want. This might be an alternative http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx

Comment: I am wondering, why should we reinvent the wheel again, it's 2012 now!, why don't Microsoft Include this forms in a template just like Register, login or Change password forms which is included!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is NO!, we must reinvent the wheel and develop the Administration panel again, i believe that Microsoft -in the feature-  will Include that in a templates just like Register and login forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an administration panel by yourself.
Means
1. You have to create pages where you can have functionality which you want to give an administrator.
2. You have to create an administrator user and password.
3. And have to check on the administration pages that only an administrator can login to an administrative page.

If I am getting your question right.This may help you.

And If this helps you plz let me know i have another more tricks to restrict the other and secure the administration page.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the biggest backdoor ever created...

Comment: I just want to use the administration features, managing roles, users security for folders..etc.

would you please show me your solution which causing that big backdoor,

Comment: @Ala - the point is that it is **not** possible, as it would represent a huge security risk - you have to employ your own solution, as astro boy suggested in the comments